# El array de dependencia de useEffect no funciona

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, useeffect

Estoy usando "useEffect" para conectarme a la API de github jobs, en el array de dependencia tengo 3 valores que cambian(location,description,full_time). El problema es que solo funciona cuando cambia el primer valor, en este caso location,si cambian los otros dos valores, a pesar de que la url cambia, obtengo la misma respuesta, y si pongo primero description, obtengo diferentes respuestas, pero si cambio location o full_time pasa lo mismo. Aquí el código que estoy usando.

```
const Home = () => {

const [description,setDescription ] = useState('');
const [location,setLocation] = useState('');
const [fulltime,setFulltime] = useState(false);


const callbackFunctionDes = (des) => {
    setDescription(des);
}

const callbackFunctionLoc = (loc) => {
    setLocation(loc);
}

const fullTime = () => {
    setFulltime(!fulltime);
}

const API = "https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?";
const cors = "https://api.allorigins.win/raw?url=";
const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    const url = API + "location="+location+"&search="+description+"&full_time="+fulltime;
    console.log(url)
    fetch(cors + url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setJobs(data);
      });
  }, [location,description,fulltime]);

return(
    <>
        <Header parentCallback={callbackFunctionDes}/>
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-3">
                    <div className="form-check my-3">
                        <input 
                            className="form-check-input" 
                            type="checkbox" 
                            value="true" 
                            id="full-time"
                            onChange={fullTime}/>
                        <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="full-time">
                          Full-time
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <Location parentCallback={callbackFunctionLoc}/>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-9">
                    <List 
                        data={jobs}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
);
```

}

Componente Header

```
const Header = (props) => {

const styles = {
    backgroundImage : `url("${Background}")`
}

const sendData = () => {
    const input = document.getElementById('query');
    props.parentCallback(input.value);
}
return(
    <header className="container my-5">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12">
                <h2><span className="font-weight-bolder">Github</span> jobs</h2>
                <div className="input-group mb-3 mx-auto p-5" style={styles}>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Title,companies or expertise" id="query"/>
                    <button 
                        className="btn btn-primary"
                        onClick={sendData}>Search</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
);
```

}

Componente Location

```
const Location = (props) => {

const sendData = (e) => {
    console.log('valor'+e.target.value);
    props.parentCallback(e.target.value);
    
}

const sendLocation = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const search = document.getElementById('search');
    console.log('valor'+search.value);
    props.parentCallback(search.value);
    search.value = "";
}


return(
    <>
        <h5 className="text-muted">LOCATION</h5>
        <form action="" >
            
            <div className="input-group mb-3">
                <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="City,state or country" id="search"/>
                <button 
                    className="btn btn-primary"
                    onClick={sendLocation}>Search</button>
            </div>
        
            <div className="form-check mt-3">
                <input 
                    className="form-check-input" 
                    type="radio" 
                    name="location" 
                    id="amsterdam"
                    value="amsterdam" 
                    onChange={sendData}/>
                <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="amsterdam">
                  Amsterdam
                </label>
            </div>
            <div className="form-check mt-3">
                <input 
                    className="form-check-input" 
                    type="radio" 
                    name="location" 
                    id="berlin" 
                    value="berlin"
                    onChange={sendData}/>
                <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="berlin">
                  Berlin
                </label>
            </div>
            <div className="form-check mt-3">
                <input 
                    className="form-check-input" 
                    type="radio" 
                    name="location" 
                    id="new_york" 
                    value="new_york"
                    onChange={sendData}/>
                <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="new_york">
                  New york
                </label>
            </div>
            <div className="form-check mt-3">
                <input 
                    className="form-check-input" 
                    type="radio" 
                    name="location" 
                    id="london" 
                    value="london"
                    onChange={sendData}/>
                <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="london">
                  London
                </label>
            </div>
        </form>
    </>
);
```

}

En la siguiente imagen, esta la prueba de que la url cambia, pero el resultado es el mismo, visite las url para corrobar y si, en cada url obtengo una respuesta diferente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, esto es Stackoverflow en español. Si quieres evitar que tu pregunta sea borrada, debes editarla y traducirla

Comment: Ok, lo siento,en un momento la edito

Comment: ¿De donde llegan `description` y `fulltime`? ¿Vienen como `props` desde un Parent Component?

Comment: @g.4 Los 3 valores tienen un state.   `const [description,setDescription ] = useState('');`     `const [location,setLocation ] = useState('');` <br/>  `const [fulltime,setFulltime] = useState(false);`

Comment: @g.4 Voy a editar la publicación para que se pueda apreciar como estoy usando el state

Comment: @EdwinMorales si pudieras compartir los componentes `Header` y `Location`, en específico como estas usando la `prop` `parentCallback`

Comment: @g.4 Listo, ya compartí los componentes Header y Location

Comment: No veo problemas con el código, ahora los parámetros de consulta son confiables si se usan por separado, pero en conjunto pueden traer diferentes combinaciones, dependiendo del orden en que se envían.

Comment: Por ejemplo, si solo uso `search` con el valor `Writer`, se obtienen 2 registros, por otro lado si solo uso `location` con el valor `Frankfurt` se obtienen 4 registros, ahí todo parece bien.

Comment: Si los uso combinados `const url = API + "location="+location+"search="+description;`, dando priopridad a location, tambien parece traer resultados consistentes, esta combinación me arroja 0 registros.

Comment: Finalmente, el que no parece funcionar es `full_time`, siempre trae los 3 tipos de trabajo `Part Time - Contract - Full Time` no los filtra, observa que estos valores estan el el parametro `type`, y se supone que esta query string `full_time`, nos debe filtrar ese parámetro ya sea con `true` o `false`, pero no logré que funcionara.

Comment: No puedo apoyarte con una respuesta, pero espero que estas notas sean de ayuda. Saludos

Comment: @g.4 No te preocupes, muchas gracias por tu apoyo y por tus observaciones.

Answer (score 1):

Encontré el error, el problema era el cors, por alguna razón el cors "https://api.allorigins.win/raw?url=" era el que siempre daba el mismo resultado a pesar de que los parametros de la url cambiaban, hice la prueba con el cors de heroku(https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/) y funciono todo correcto, así que básicamente ese era el error.

Comment: Muy interesante el uso de cors para las peticiones API, hay que tener presentes estos conceptos, saludos